# Image browse button in android activity

Tags: android, imageview, file-browser

currently I'm developing an application which requires a browse button in my activity. When I press the browse button I should be able to browse the image files in my sdcard as well as in the phone memory. Upon tapping the image file it should be selected and the path of the image file (that is, where that selected image file is located) should be displayed in the activity in a textview. Also the selected image should be displayed in a imageview. How to do this? Can someone please help me out..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Credits for the following solution: [How To Pick Image From Gallery in Android App](https://www.viralpatel.net/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/) by [Viral Patel](https://www.viralpatel.net/author/viral/).

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yourpackage;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     
     
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
     
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         
        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                 
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }
     
     
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
 
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
 
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
             
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
         
        }
     
     
    }
}
```

Add Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` is deprecated. So @Looking_Forward bro's code will not work on android 10+. But just with a simple modification, I worked @Looking_Forward bro's code. Process below:

After `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();` line remove all code and just use `Glide.with(this).load(selectedImage).into(imageView)` (this is Glide library). Also it's much easier then use contentProvider (which is @Looking_Forward bro showed).