# adding picture in imageview by user selection

Tags: java, android

i want to add picture in an image view with the text veiw in one line. this code is opening the gallery and let me select a picture. but when the picture is selected the picture is then not showed in the image veiw. i took the code from this link
[[Image browse button in android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072034/image-browse-button-in-android-activity])

here is my code

```
     image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,

     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
```

and

```
             @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,    
            Intent data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null   

       != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


       }
```

and here is the xml

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"

        android:layout_weight="0.5"
       />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"


        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget permission read external storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You can use Log.d("TAG", "picturePath: "+ picturePath);
If log not show, you can check build version code, Android version M or higher requirement permission read external storage.
If log show, you can check absolute path image and search "load bitmap from external storage".
I hope my answer can help you!